# Separate image galleries in a page with imagelightbox.js

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I am using Osvaldas Valutis' excellent imagelightbox.js script (http://osvaldas.info/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly). It works fine, but it doesn't allow me to divide a bunch of images into separate galleries within the same page (it iterates ALL images).

I would like to have all images in the page to have the same data attribute (data-imagelightbox="b") so that they all display in the same way, but find a method to group them into separate galleries, so that when you open one image that belongs to a gallery of 3, it only iterates those 3 images, and then you can close this gallery, and open the next.

```
<div class="gallery-1">
<a href="images/big/a-1.png" data-imagelightbox="b" class="gal-1">thumb</a>
<a href="images/big/a-2.png" data-imagelightbox="b" class="gal-1">thumb</a>
<a href="images/big/a-3.png" data-imagelightbox="b" class="gal-1">thumb</a>
</div>
<div class="gallery-2">
<a href="images/big/b-1.png" data-imagelightbox="b" class="gal-2">thumb</a>
<a href="images/big/b-2.png" data-imagelightbox="b" class="gal-2">thumb</a>
<a href="images/big/b-3.png" data-imagelightbox="b" class="gal-2">thumb</a>
</div>
```

I assumed the best way to do this would be to use different selectors to separate images into galleries, for example:

```
var galleries = [ '.gal-1', '.gal-2', '.gal-3', '.gal-4' ];
$.each( galleries, function()
{
$( selector ).imageLightbox();
});
```

But the above code doesn't work (it throws an error "undefined selector") and keeps on opening the 6 images above in a complete sequence, instead of dividing them into two different sets...

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method actually works, just in case anyone else encountered the same problem:

```
var galleries = [ '.animals', '.flowers', '.trees', '.birds' ]; $.each( galleries,
function() { $( selector ).imageLightbox(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

*Earlier answer deleted*

**Edit**

After studying the [demo page](http://osvaldas.info/examples/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly/), it would appear that separate galleries are formed by specifying the value of `data-imagelightbox` for each gallery before invoking `.imageLightbox()` on the collection, which is a bit crazy but hey-ho!

You can set `data-imagelightbox` values in HTML but it's probably easier to do so in javascript, as follows :

```
$(".gallery-1 a").data('imagelightbox', 'a').imageLightbox();
$(".gallery-2 a").data('imagelightbox', 'b').imageLightbox();
$(".gallery-3 a").data('imagelightbox', 'c').imageLightbox();
$(".gallery-4 a").data('imagelightbox', 'd').imageLightbox();
```

Thus :

- your class names `class="gal-1"`, `class="gal-2"` etc are not used and can be deleted.
- the hard-coded `data-imagelightbox="b"` attributes are overridden and can be deleted.

Comment: None of these methods seem to work. Images iterate between galleries continuously, instead of just iterating the images within each gallery.

Comment: Then maybe imageLightbox can't do multiple galleries. If the documentation were better, then we might know.

Comment: According to its author, it can support multiple galleries, using the method I suggested above. It is the implementation of that method that seems to be faulty... hence my question here...

Comment: I have deleted my first answer and written another. If it still doesn't work, then I will give up.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that having different data-imagelightbox attributes, galleries are displayed differently, which is why I indicated in my question that ALL galleries needed to have the same data-imagelightbox="b" attribute, which dictates the look of the lightbox (each of the data-imagelightbox attributes displays the lightbox differently: with or without captions, with or without close icon, with or without arrows, etc).

Comment: As far as I can tell, having different data-imagelightbox attributes is the *only* way to have separate galleries. Controlling appearance is a separate issue. You have to find a way to give all galleries the same appearance. I'm sure that's not too hard.

Comment: Allowed data-imagelightbox attributes are limited(a to g), which control which different elements to display. If you use, say, data-imagelightbox="m", the script doesn't work.

Comment: Where is "a to g" documented?

Comment: It is not. It just is the way it seems to work: adding further imagelightbox attributes results in the script not working, whereas if you use a to g, it does, with different elements being displayed.

Comment: As I understand it, a to g are just labels used in the inageLightbox demo page. Each letter is given its own appearance/behaviour by a combination of CSS and the object map passed to `.imageLightbox()`; there should be noting to prevent you defining two or more independent galleries with the *same* appearance/behaviour if that's what you want. Also, I can see no reason why you should be confined to 'a', 'b' etc. 'gallery1', 'gallery2' should work just as well.

Comment: user3596725, it's best if you post that as an answer, together with the associated HTML. You should then be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this plugin. I wanted to create 3 galleries with the same data attribute. Each gallery would have one thumbnail opening multiple images.

What I did with each gallery:

```
<div class="gallery1">
  <a href="/1.jpg" rel="group1" data-imagelightbox="f">
     <img src="images/gallery1.jpg">
  </a>
 <a href="/2.jpg" rel="group1" data-imagelightbox="f">
     <img style="display: none;" src="" alt="Example"/> /* This helped find the image */
 </a>
</div>
```

In the javascript I duplicate same functions for "f" but changed it for a new letter "x", and so on.. Each gallery now works independently.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this had been my solution and is working absolutely fine,
I hope this can help someone.

I placed this in my JS script after the lightbox configuration:

```
var dataSelector = '';
$(GALLERY_CONTAINER_SELECTOR).each(function(index, el) {
  dataSelector = $(this).find(IMAGE_ANCHOR_SELECTOR).attr('data-imagelightbox');

  var selector = 'a[data-imagelightbox="' + dataSelector + '"]';
  var instance = $(selector).imageLightbox({
    onStart:    function() { overlayOn(); closeButtonOn( instance );  },
    onEnd:      function() { overlayOff(); captionOff(); closeButtonOff(); activityIndicatorOff(); },
    onLoadStart:  function() { captionOff(); activityIndicatorOn(); },
    onLoadEnd:    function() { captionOn(); activityIndicatorOff(); }
  });
});
```

And HTML looks like:

```
<div class="GALLERY_CONTAINER_SELECTOR">
  <a class="IMAGE_ANCHOR_SELECTOR" href="IMAGE_URL_1" data-imagelightbox="YOUR_GALLERY_NAME">IMAGE_1</a>
  <a class="IMAGE_ANCHOR_SELECTOR" href="IMAGE_URL_2" data-imagelightbox="YOUR_GALLERY_NAME">IMAGE_2</a>
  <a class="IMAGE_ANCHOR_SELECTOR" href="IMAGE_URL_3" data-imagelightbox="YOUR_GALLERY_NAME">IMAGE_3</a>
  <!-- Add as many images as needed -->
</div>
```